# How to remove stop words from a large collection files with more efficient way?

Tags: java, algorithm, stop-words

I have 200,000 files for which I've to process and extract tokens for each file. The size of all files is 1.5GB. When I wrote the code for extracting tokens from each file, it works well. Over all execution time is 10mins.

After that, I tried to remove `stopwords` Performance went down badly. It's taking 25 to 30 mins.

I'm using stop words from the website [here](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume5/lewis04a/a11-smart-stop-list/english.stop) There are around 571 stop words. The general procedure is to extract each stop word from a text file at once and compare with each token in the file.

This is the stub of code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : tokens)
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("stopwords.txt"));
    while(sc.hasNext())
    {
        if(sc.next().equals(s)){
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        sb.append(s + "\n" );
    flag = false;
}
String str = sb.toString()
```

**Ignore errors.

The performance of above code is at least 10 times less than below code. It takes 50 to 60 mins to execute.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s = tokens.toString();
String str = s.replaceAll("StopWord1|Stopword2|Stopword3|........|LastStopWord"," ");
```

Performance is far good. This takes 20 to 25 mins.

Is there any better procedure?

Comment: Put your stop words in a `HashSet<String>` and use `set.contains(word)` to determine if a word is a stop word. That should be efficient.

Comment: Do you use multi-threading? It will help dramatically if you don't.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm using 6 threads..

Comment: 6 threads? You are making this complicated. You are cpu bound and disk. Threads won't help you that much.

Comment: yeah.. I'm trying to figure out.. My PC has good config..

Comment: @Brain  suggest about Apache Lucene API. I just try to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this is bad. You are doing `O(n^2)` comparisons. For every word you are comparing with another word. You need to rethink your algorithm.

Read all the stop words in to a `HashSet<String>` and then just check `set.contains(word)`. This will improve your performance dramatically.

Comment: Instead of reading from scanner and comparing, read from scanner and put in set using. `set.add(word)`.

Comment: Out of curiosity is this the difference between reading something within a set/list versus reading with scanner? Scanner is slow?

Comment: Yes there is a huge difference. The answer is too big for this question. But you are hitting disk vs memory. Also set is O(1) look up time vs list is O(n). So there is a lot of differences.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the [Apache Lucene API](https://lucene.apache.org)

It provides functionality for indexing files and removing stopwords, stemming tokens, search, and document similarity based on LSA

Comment: Can give more specific link to get there?