# Removing stopwords from a String in Java

Tags: java, string, stop-words

I have a string with lots of words and I have a text file which contains some Stopwords which I need to remove from my String. 
Let's say I have a String

```
s="I love this phone, its super fast and there's so much new and cool things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs."
```

After removing stopwords, string should be like :

```
"love phone, super fast much cool jelly bean....but recently bugs."
```

I have been able to achieve this but the problem I am facing is that whenver there are adjacent stopwords in the String its removing only the first and I am getting result as :

```
"love phone, super fast there's much and cool with jelly bean....but recently seen bugs"
```

Here's my stopwordslist.txt file :
    [Stopwords](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hcd0fw8i6uwfnkr/stopwordslist.txt?dl=0)

How can I solve this problem. Here's what I have done so far :

```
int k=0,i,j;
ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
String sCurrentLine;
String[] stopwords = new String[2000];
try{
        FileReader fr=new FileReader("F:\\stopwordslist.txt");
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            stopwords[k]=sCurrentLine;
            k++;
        }
        String s="I love this phone, its super fast and there's so much new and cool things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs.";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s);
        String[] words = builder.toString().split("\\s");
        for (String word : words){
            wordsList.add(word);
        }
        for(int ii = 0; ii < wordsList.size(); ii++){
            for(int jj = 0; jj < k; jj++){
                if(stopwords[jj].contains(wordsList.get(ii).toLowerCase())){
                    wordsList.remove(ii);
                    break;
                }
             }
        }
        for (String str : wordsList){
            System.out.print(str+" ");
        }   
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Comment: would splitting the string first help? something like "phrase.split(delims);"  you can filter off the unwanted parts before stitching them back again. this may resolve your "This" and "his" problem.

Comment: [More specific question is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257598/best-way-to-remove-stop-words-from-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you remove element from the list you iterate on.
Let says you have `wordsList` that contains `|word0|word1|word2|`
If `ii` is equal to `1` and the if test is true, then you call `wordsList.remove(1);`. After that your list is `|word0|word2|`. `ii` is then incremented and is equal to `2` and now it's above the size of your list, hence `word2` will never be tested.

From there there is several solutions. For example instead of removing values you can set value to "". Or create a special "result" list.

Answer (score 5):

This is a much more elegant solution (IMHO), using only regular expressions:

```
    // instead of the ".....", add all your stopwords, separated by "|"
    // "\\b" is to account for word boundaries, i.e. not replace "his" in "this"
    // the "\\s?" is to suppress optional trailing white space
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(I|this|its.....)\\b\\s?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("I love this phone, its super fast and there's so much new and cool things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs.");
    String s = m.replaceAll("");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: It's not the break statement at all the problem. He takes in the first loop the first word of the text. Then he looks in the list of stopwords if it is present. If he find the word in the stopword list he break the search loop. Then he takes the next word and search again in the stopword list.

Comment: again, as with other answers you will remove the stopwords that are substrings of normal words.

Comment: @alain.janinm you're right, guess I was trying to be too fast. Since you already provided the correct answer I've just removed the silly remark from my answer.

Comment: @MichalLozinski correct, I've updated my answer to include word boundaries.

Comment: @geert3 Thanks for taking my comment into account ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try the program below.

```
String s="I love this phone, its super fast and there's so" +
            " much new and cool things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs.";
    String[] words = s.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> stopWordsSet = new HashSet<String>();
    stopWordsSet.add("I");
    stopWordsSet.add("THIS");
    stopWordsSet.add("AND");
    stopWordsSet.add("THERE'S");

    for(String word : words)
    {
        String wordCompare = word.toUpperCase();
        if(!stopWordsSet.contains(wordCompare))
        {
            wordsList.add(word);
        }
    }

    for (String str : wordsList){
        System.out.print(str+" ");
    }
```

OUTPUT:
love phone, its super fast so much new cool things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs.

Comment: Nice catch, not removing the unwanted ones, but adding the wanted ones! +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use replace All function like this

```
String yourString ="I love this phone, its super fast and there's so much new and cool things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs."
yourString=yourString.replaceAll("stop" ,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's try it following way:

```
   String s="I love this phone, its super fast and there's so much new and cool things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs.";
   String stopWords[]={"love","this","cool"};
   for(int i=0;i<stopWords.length;i++){
       if(s.contains(stopWords[i])){
           s=s.replaceAll(stopWords[i]+"\\s+", ""); //note this will remove spaces at the end
       }
   }
   System.out.println(s);
```

This way you final output will be without the words you don't want in it. Just get a list of stop words in an array and replace in required string.
**Output for my stopwords:**

```
I   phone, its super fast and there's so much new and  things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs.
```

Comment: after the for loop, s=s.replaceAll("<two space>","<single space>"); to change the two spaces to a single space ?

Comment: Also, just as with Vimal's aswer you would remove substrings from the middle of other words (try adding "a" as a stopword ;))

Answer (score 1):

Instead why don't you use below approach. It will be easier to read and understand :

```
for(String word : words){
    s = s.replace(word+"\\s*", "");
}
System.out.println(s);//It will print removed word string.
```

Comment: do note that this implementation will result in two spaces.

Comment: The problem with this is that it will also remove the stopwords in between of other words. Like it removes "his" from "this" also.

Comment: also this means that for large stop-word tables, this is not an optimal solution, as you'd iterate over everything regardless of how long your text is. Still if your stop-words set will stay this big than indeed, this is one of the simplest answers :)

Comment: and if the stop-word is the last word, it'll leave a blank space at the end of the sentence.

Comment: I think that, to fix the issues in comments, you would need a following regexp: `format("( %s )|(^%s )|( %s$)", word)`
Than you should replace matches with spaces and afterward remove all the double spaces.
Still with all that mombo-jumbo this starts to look messy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) api of String like:

```
String myString = "I love this phone, its super fast and there's so much new and cool things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs.";
String stopWords = "I|its|with|but";
String afterStopWords = myString.replaceAll("(" + stopWords + ")\\s*", "");
System.out.println(afterStopWords);

OUTPUT: 
love this phone, super fast and there's so much new and cool things jelly bean....of recently 've seen some bugs.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the stopwords in a set collection, and than tokenise your string to a list.
You can afterwards simply use 'removeAll' to get the result.

```
Set<String> stopwords = new Set<>()
//fill in the set with your file

String s="I love this phone, its super fast and there's so much new and cool things with jelly bean....but of recently I've seen some bugs.";
List<String> listOfStrings = asList(s.split(" "));

listOfStrings.removeAll(stopwords);
StringUtils.join(listOfStrings, " ");
```

No for loops needed - they usually mean problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you make a stop one stop word is removed in a sentence move to another stop word: you need to remove all stop words in each sentence.

You should try changing your code:

## From:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < wordsList.size(); ii++){
    for(int jj = 0; jj < k; jj++){
        if(stopwords[jj].contains(wordsList.get(ii).toLowerCase())){
            wordsList.remove(ii);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

## To something like:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < wordsList.size(); ii++)
{
    for(int jj = 0; jj < k; jj++)
    {
        if(wordsList.get(ii).toLowerCase().contains(stopwords[jj])
        {
            wordsList.remove(ii);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `break` is removed and `stopword.contains(word)` is changed to  `word.contains(stopword)`.

Answer (score 0):

Recently one of the project required the functionality to filter the stopping/stemm and swear words from the given text or file, after going through the few blogs and write-ups.
created a simple library to filter data/file and made available in maven. hope this may help some one.

https://github.com/uttesh/exude

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.uttesh</groupId>
        <artifactId>exude</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is a buggy library

Comment: @MFARID could you please provide the explanation on what basis it is buggy library?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void myStopWords(ArrayList stopWordCollection) {
    stopWordCollection.add("a");
    stopWordCollection.add("and");
    stopWordCollection.add("is");
    stopWordCollection.add("the");
    stopWordCollection.add("are");
    stopWordCollection.add("of");
    stopWordCollection.add("in");
    stopWordCollection.add("for");
    stopWordCollection.add("where");
    stopWordCollection.add("when");
    }
   private static void myStopWordRemoval(String text,ArrayList 
    list,ArrayList stopWordCollection) {

    List<String> list2=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<stopWordCollection.size();j++) {
            if(list.get(i).equals(stopWordCollection.get(j)))
                list2.add(list.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
```